# Building docker for the ARM-64 architecture

Tags: docker, compilation, arm, arm64

I have been trying to compile docker for the ARM-64 architecture. Docker doesn’t officially support ARM 64-bits (at least not through the package management tools); hence I have to build it from source. Building docker binary set needs docker itself as a dependency. I’ve already managed to compile both the docker daemon and the client via the following (hack) command:

```
./hack/make.sh dynbinary
```

However, I haven’t managed to run it successfully. Both binaries are compiled and work, but when I want to start up the daemon it complains about other dependencies:

```
Failed to connect to containerd. Please make sure containerd is installed in your PATH or you have specified the correct address. Got error: exec: "docker-containerd": executable file not found in $PATH
```

As I mentioned earlier, I cannot build all the binaries as they need docker itself running.

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: you should read https://resin.io/blog/building-arm-containers-on-any-x86-machine-even-dockerhub/

Comment: Have you looked at the Raspberry Pi setup? https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/docker-comes-to-raspberry-pi/

Comment: @user2915097, I want to run docker on ARM-64, I don't want to emulate anything. That's not related.

Comment: @BMitch, this doesn't work on ARM-64; it's for ARM-32.

Answer (score 1):

Two weeks ago, I was able to install Docker on a Pine64 running Armbian (Debian based). It was as easy as following [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/debian/#set-up-the-repository) for armhf with one exception, change `[arch=armhf]` by `[arch=arm64]` when you add the new apt source.

After the install you have a real Arm64 docker running :

```
root@pine64:~# docker system info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 60
Server Version: 17.12.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 28
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 89623f28b87a6004d4b785663257362d1658a729
runc version: b2567b37d7b75eb4cf325b77297b140ea686ce8f
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.107-pine64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
OSType: linux
Architecture: aarch64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 979.6MiB
Name: pine64
ID: xxx
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: xxx
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```